# suppose f,g are positive and monotonic functions, does that mean that f belongs to O(g) or g belongs to O(f)?

Tags: runtime

I was asked this question today by a student, and I know the answer is false, but I cant seem to find the correct example to disprove this.
I tried using n and nlogn however that cant work because n belongs to nlogn.
any ideas?